# CSS font size using em different on different pages

Tags: html, css, font-size

CSS is not my forte so this might be something simple. I have set my footer font size in a stylesheet using 0.8em but on different pages it is a different size. I'm only editing someone elses work and he did a poor job at not closing tags so its a bit painful.

Is there a way to clear all font settings so that the footer is the same across all pages? Or is this a problem that can be solved some other way?

Cheers for any help.

Comment: Can you post a link to the site? This is difficult to troubleshoot without seeing the font-size definitions on various pages.

Comment: Its on an intranet sorry. The previous site designer only used inline css using the <FONT> tag but never closed ANY of them. There are about 20-50 on each page.

Comment: If you have the `<font>` tag in use, the page is, if at all possible, due for a redesign. `<font>` was deprecated in html 4.0 transitional, and *invalid* for html 4.0 strict. Assuming a largely IE-based intranet, and the difficulties of developing for IE *without* a valid doctype, I do think it'd be worth the while/cost. But...I suppose you'd need a business case to justify the cost. Poor guy. =/ (reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/graphics.html#edef-FONT)

Comment: is Text-Size set on some of these pages where sizes are different? Which browser are you trying this?

Comment: David - I agree but unfortunately I don't own the site and it was purchased as a Application written in VBScript by them. Unfortunately there is nothing I can do. Anero - Not that I can see. Its the same problem in all browsers.

Comment: @Rudiger, that's fair enough. It's just, y'know, *ewwwww* =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was basically to do inline styles to correct any problems. Using px rather than em was an option but we preferred to keep accessibility rather than best practice against using inline styles (any best practice was out the window anyway).

Comment: I suggest using Firebug for FireFox (Chrome has something native, IE as well but it's quite bad in comparison) and checking what styles apply on the element, inherited or not, overruled or not. It is then easy to figure out where the different size is coming from by seeing what extra rule is being applied to the black-sheep element.

Comment: Uhm, in this case it doesn't really seem like it would be a pleasant read. x_x

Answer (score 14):

I notice no one has touched on how `em` works as a font size unit, so I'll try to clear that up for you.

There are two ways to tell the browser how large your fonts should be rendered.

1. setting an *absolute* size
   For *absolute* sizes, like `px` or `pt`, you're telling the browser exactly what size you want the text to be. If you write `12px`, it's going to come out as exactly 12 pixels tall.
2. setting a **relative** size — `em` is a **relative** size.
   For **relative** sizes, like **`em`**, you're telling the browser how big to make the text with respect to other text on the page. This works sort of like a percentage, so if your footer text is sized at **`0.8em`**, it will be rendered 80% as tall as the main text on the page.

This explains why you're getting different sizes on different pages. If the font size of the body is set explicitly on one page, but not set at all on another (or set explicitly to a different size) that will make your `em`-sized fonts render at different sizes.

This is also why it's really bad to use `<font>` tags. It's going to be a serious pain to dig around those tags and figure out what explicit sizes are being set that might be throwing off your `em`s.
When you set your font sizes using CSS, this is not only an information which is easy to find, but also a property which is easy to modify.

Answer (score 1):

As David Thomas says, the use of `<font>` is deprecated. If you have a software tool to do global edits, you might try deleting all the `<font>` tags and then add classes back to the HTML that actually needs to be different fonts and add the font info to the CSS.
The other option is to get through one at a time, which I imagine to be time consuming. At least you would have cleaner HTML when you were done.

In a weak defense, the previous designer may have used a WYSIWYG web design tool that created the HTML for him/her and didn't see the resulting code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an exact size with `px` or `pt` units rather than `em`.
Sizes in percent and `em` can get screwed up by unintended levels of inheritance but not `px` or `pt`.

Comment: Try putting salt on your cakes rather than sugar. Sugar can cause cavities or diabetes, but not salt. :(