# Why are em font sizes different for the same value?

Tags: html, css

On one page `1em` equals `16px` and on another it's `19.6px`.

**Main questions:**

- Why is that?
- And how can i get around this?

I have a feeling that if work with this as it is it will change again, and maybe even on the same page? I have read the first few articles that pop up in google search, found nothing relevant on the issue. I get that it's relative, but relative to what exactly? And how can i create some sort of consistency for all the pages on my site?

Filler code so i can actually submit the question:

```html
    <h1 class="product-info__title">Rombat Premier</h1>

    <div class="product-info__type-specification">
        Autovehicule cu consumatori electrici suplimentar
    </div>

    <ul class="product-info__features">
        <li>Cea mai buna oferta calitativa Rombat</li>
        <li>Baterie etansa</li>
        <li>Capace duplex cu indicator de stare si arestor de flacara</li>
        <li>Capace cu dopuri "push in", care asigura etansare totala</li>
        <li>Gratare expandate din aliaj PbCa</li>
        <li>Curent de pornire mai mare cu 30% fata de clasa Cyclon</li>
        <li>Suporta un numar mare de ciclari</li>
        <li>Durata de viata sporita</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp `em Relative to the font-size of the element `

Comment: As above it uses the size of the relative parent to calculate it. If you want to calculate the size based off of the base body font-size, use `rem`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713840/css-font-size-using-em-different-on-different-pages

Comment: saw both of those, still no indication on how should i actually handle this to get some consistency

Comment: @JonathanSzekely use `rem` as stated above