# New page with same css file rendering with a different font size

Tags: html, css

So heres all my code I'm quite new to web design so I might of made a few mistakes. The problem is that when I load the about me page the font size for the navigation is smaller. I've tried looking for anwsers but none make sense to me. Can you help? I've never made a post on here before so forgive m if the code looks messy.

**Page 1**

```
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="main.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="index.html">Gallery</a> </li><!-- commenting out white space caused by display: inline-block 
                    --><li> <a href="about_me.html">About Me</a> </li><!--
                    --><li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
```

---

**Page 2**

```
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="main.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="index.html">Gallery</a> </li><!-- commenting out white space caused by display: inline-block 
                    --><li> <a href="about_me.html">About Me</a> </li><!--
                    --><li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
```

---

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

hr{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 2% auto; 
}

header{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 14%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    position: relative;
}

nav{
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    /*background-color: green;*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    bottom: 0px;
}

nav ul{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 28%;
    margin: 0 1%;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    /*background-color: #aaa;*/
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: #000;
}

nav ul li a:link{
    background-color: #aaa;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #ff5588;
}

nav ul li a:active{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it will help you. You can  check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713840/css-font-size-using-em-different-on-different-pages

Comment: You can view what styles are being applied or overwritten using browser inspect tools. In Chrome or Firefox right-click the page or element and select inspect. (You may need to turn developer tools on. Google will help you with that)

Comment: I opened your two pages in a text-comparison program and they are identical. I'm under the impression that your issue may be something to do with caching. Did you recently update the font-size in the CSS file when this issue began? Try changing your `main.css` include to be `main.css?2` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @ReeceBarrett You didn't copy+paste the same code twice. I edited your question so that your pages were split up instead of being in one code block, and that only the relevant portion of code was included. Being that it's the `nav` you're having trouble with, i only left this, as well as any parents it has that could pass down styles. It's good practice to post only the pieces of code you're having trouble with and necessary context, rather than entire pages worth of code for users to dig through.

Comment: This being said, try what mhatch said, and try my commented solution. Your `<nav>` elements are identical.

Comment: @Santi oh right I wondered how my question had been edited. I didnt realise other people could do that. And no I didnt recently update the font-size. I was trying to get a:active selector to work. so I created a new page to test it by copying the nav as I want it the same on each page. but for some reason the font size has changed.

Comment: @ReeceBarrett Is your new page in the same folder as the first?

Comment: @Santi yes everything is in just one folder

Comment: @mhatch I have tried inspecting the element in firefox. And nothing is being overwritten as far as I can see.

Comment: @ReeceBarrett You should also be able to see what styles are being Applied as well. If there is a discrepancy you should be able to find it. Then you can diagnose where the problem is coming from. Paths and caching are both good guesses.

Comment: As Santi pointed out, there is nothing in the code provided that is causing the problem. You will need to diagnose further or provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I have looked at the styles etc. and there is no difference between both pages. so why it is doing this i have no idea. I dont know what paths and catching are so i'll research into that. thanks

Comment: @ReeceBarrett You don't have a website that you can provide a link to?